# Amazon S3 - Limit size of objects that can be put in a bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Does anyone know how I can edit Bucket Policy to resrict object size with PUT command? I know that I should use "[The Condition Block](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_condition.html)" but I couldn't figure out which one will give me object size.

Answer (score 0):

I looked through all possible conditions in aws and there is no condition that gives object size limit. There is a workaround though.

- Create a lambda function that triggers when an object is uploaded to S3.
- Get the object in lambda through "event.object"
- Check if it exceeds max file size.
- Delete if the check returns true.

If you find another way, please let us know.
Have a great day...